# IIS Server to tomcat communication >Websockets are not supported by AJP protocol,

Tags: tomcat, iis, websocket, isapi, ajp

We have  installed IIS Server in front of tomcat server, now browser request hits IIS Server and then goes to tomcat. Everything is working fine for http request but for websocket I am getting exception in the backed as  HTTP Upgrade is not supported by AJP Protocol.

AJP protocol doesn't support websockets and we have to use only IIS Server.

How do I make websockets working ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your post doesn't seem to contain any actual questions, and thus it's kinda hard to answer.

Comment: [1] You need to provide a lot more information. [2] In particular, describe the existing configuration for your web socket requests in IIS and Tomcat, and post the exception you are getting. Also, show any other information that may be relevant such as error messages in the ISAPI logs. [3] See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for general information on improving your question.

Comment: HttpPlatformHandler should work https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manjug/2015/11/27/understanding-iis-httpplatformhandler-using-tomcat-8/